# Set Label to pre-defined text symbol from gallery ArcPy and CIM

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, cartographic-information-model

In ArcPy (ArcGIS Pro 2.5), I am looking to set a label symbol to a pre-defined text style from the gallery. I'm hoping I can do something like this:

```
    lblClass.visible = "True"
    lyr.showLabels = True
    
    # Get CIM definition
    l_cim = lyr.getDefinition('V2')
    lc = l_cim.labelClasses[0] # Returns first CIMLabelClass object
    
    lc.textSymbol.symbol.applySymbolFromGallery("label1")
    # Update CIM defintion
    lyr.setDefinition(l_cim)
```

Any ideas?